# React Native Context setUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, expo, react-context

I am trying to use React Context to manage if the user is signed in or not. What I have so far is something like this:

```
import AuthUserContext, { AuthUserProvider } from './Components/auth/AuthUserProvider';

function App() {
  const {user, setUser} = React.useContext(AuthUserContext)
  setUser('') // SetUser is not a function
}
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
var user: any, setUser: any;

const AuthUserContext = React.createContext({user, setUser});
export default AuthUserContext;

export const AuthUserProvider = ({ children } : {children: any}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  
  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthUserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

AuthUserProvider.tsx

Here's the error:

```
TypeError: setUser is not a function. (In 'setUser('')', 'setUser' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
```

I'm new to react native and have been trying to fix this for hours. Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Where is the AuthUserProvider in the component tree, relative to the App? It must be an ancestor of App, or app will get the default values, which are undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

It seems the initial value of your context is undefined.

```
var user: any, setUser: any;

const AuthUserContext = React.createContext({ user, setUser }); // both undefined
```

## Solution

Define the shape of the context.

```
var user: any, setUser: any;

const AuthUserContext = React.createContext({
  user: '',
  setUser: () => {}, // <-- indicate setUser is a function
});
```

See [Updating Context from a Nested Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component)

Comment: Works! Had to play around with types for a bit but you were right. Thanks so much!